# EFI partition of the HFS formatted external hard drive won't mount in macOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-utility

#### General Description of the issue

**Initial Cause:** When I was copying some files to the external drive, the copying operation froze half way. I couldn't eject the drive so I just unplugged it.

**What happened next:** I plugged the drive back, my Mac recognized it since it appeared on the desktop and the sidebar of the finder. But there were nothing there, all I got was a blank finder tab, though the files seemed intact because the info panel said 59GB out of 2TB left.

**Further findings:** With this corrupted external drive plugged in, I couldn't open the disk utility or any software that scans the drive, and the preference pane "startup disk" showed no disks, and the finder just froze sometimes. When I chose to restart the computer, the computer won't even shut down until I unplugged the external drive. And as expected, the computer won't start up with the drive plugged in.

---

#### Previous Approach

**Disk Utility:** I previously mentioned that DU won't start with the drive plugged in, but I opened DU first and plugged the drive next and DU recognized it like there were nothing wrong. I ran first aid on the drive itself (disk2) and its only partition (disk2s2). Operation on disk2 failed due to "Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting" and the operation on disk2s2 failed due to that the disk failed to unmount.

**Terminal:** I performed several commands in the terminal but they didn't help.

```
diskutil verifyDisk disk2
Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting  
Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup

diskutil verifyVolume disk2s1
Volume is already unmounted  
Performing fsck_msdos -n /dev/rdisk2s1  
** /dev/rdisk2s1  
could not read boot block (Resource busy)  
File system check exit code is 8  
Restoring the original state found as unmounted  
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed  
Underlying error: 8: Exec format error

diskutil verifyVolume disk2s2
Verifying file system  
Volume could not be unmounted  
Using live mode  
Performing fsck_hfs -fn -l -x /dev/rdisk2s2  
File system check exit code is 8  
Restoring the original state found as mounted  
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed  
Underlying error: 8: Exec format error  

diskutil repairDisk disk2
Repairing the partition map might erase disk2s1, proceed? (y/N) y  
Started partition map repair on disk2  
Checking prerequisites  
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map  
Error: -69808: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup  

diskutil repairVolume disk2s1
Started file system repair on disk2s1 EFI  
Repairing file system  
Volume is already unmounted  
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk2s1  
** /dev/rdisk2s1  
could not read boot block (Resource busy)
File system check exit code is 8
Restoring the original state found as unmounted
Error: -69845: File system verify or repair failed
Underlying error: 8: Exec format error

diskutil repairVolume disk2s2
Started file system repair on disk2s2  
Repairing file system  
Volume could not be unmounted  
Restoring the original state found as mounted  
Error: -69673: Unable to unmount volume for repair
```

#### I also did some force unmount

```
disk2: Forced unmount of disk2 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted. 
disk2s1(EFI): disk2s1 was already unmounted  
disk2s2: Volume on disk2s2 timed out while waiting to unmount.
```

And some `fsck` on every partition. But none of them helped, and they only returned "volumeType is 0". The grep fsck also didn't help.

#### Current Thoughts

Since the above efforts indicate that disk2s1(EFI) is always unmounted and disk2s2 is always mounted, and the external disk itself is interfering with the Finder and the system, I guess the EFI partition is corrupted.

I bought a new 2TB external drive and tried to copy the corrupted disk but failed. I tried both disk utility and the Time Machine, neither of them could perform the restoring or backing up with the corrupted disk involved.

So I wonder if there are any solutions to fix the drive, or at least I hope to find a way to back up the corrupted drive.

Comment: You mean **rescue** the corrupted drive. Backups are what you do before disaster strikes, not afterwards. Basically, choose your Rescue software solution. I'd always try DiskWarrior first, Disk Drill, Drive Genius or TechTool Pro after that.